# Difference between join and select query within column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I came across this SQL that has a select statement in the column names of outer query:

```
select w1, w2, w3, (select s from parttype where parttype.p = wt.p) s
from wtype wt
   where
       pcode = 'aPcode'
   and ccode = 'aCcode'
```

And it returns a result like this:

```
w1 | w2 | w3 | s
---|----|----|---
 0 | 1  |  G | F
```

It was confusing to me, so I rewrote it like this:

```
select w1, w2, w3, wt.s
from wtype wt, parttype
   where
       pcode = 'aPcode'
   and ccode = 'aCcode'
   and parttype.p = wt.p
```

This query too returns the same result:

```
w1 | w2 | w3 | s
---|----|----|---
 0 | 1  |  G | F
```

Now, what is bugging me is whether I have translated *correctly* the SQL above by my re-written SQL below, or is my re-written SQL an improper translation. Currently though I am getting same result for both the queries for any value I use for `pcode` and `ccode`.

**Q.** Is the lower SQL query a correct translation or an alternative way to perform the upper SQL query?

---

If that helps, both table has a common column, named `s`

Comment: The join is safer. (If the sub-query returns more than 1 row, you'll get an error.)

Comment: What does the query execution plan tell you? The result is the same as long as there's only one entry in `parttype`, the way data is queried is different. Basically the first should yield the same results as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because the `INNER JOIN` skips rows without entries in `parttype`.

Comment: @jarlh That's exactly what I thought in the very first place, that made me rewrite it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ And please use proper `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Is comma separating table names to join *wrong*? Please help me with a pointer. And why is that not *proper*, please?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ The explicit `JOIN` syntax has been introduced decades ago. It is safer as it *requires* the join condition. The syntax you're using can more easily lead to errors if you forget the actual join condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get different behaviour if there happens to be multiple rows in `parttype` with the same `p` value.

The first query will generate an error. The second query will generate multiple result rows. Which of those you deem to be correct is not known.

You'll also get different behaviour if there is *no* row in `parttype` for a particular `p` value (as Thorsten points out in the comments). If you want to replicate that behaviour, you need a `LEFT JOIN`.

A better re-write would be to use an explicit join:

```
select w1, w2, w3, wt.s
from wtype wt
inner join parttype pt
        on
           wt.p = pt.p
where
       pcode = 'aPcode'
   and ccode = 'aCcode'
```

They've only been a standard part of SQL since 1992.

Comment: Surely one that has possibility of generating error is not deemed correct. :) Is there any difference between explicit join and the join by comma separating the table names as I did? And why is explicit join better?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - one that generates an error may alert you to an issue with your data, whereas one that merrily produces results you didn't expect (producing two or more rows when you only expected one) may allow you to continue and make incorrect decisions or corrupt other data. So as I say, it's unclear which behaviour is the desired one. Explicit join is definitely preferred if you want to achieve the `LEFT JOIN` rather than an inner one and is less easy to screw up (by e.g. forgetting to include the join conditions in the where clause).